# Spring DM and Services registry

Tags: java, spring, osgi, bundle, spring-dm

I'm learning Spring DM and I have a problem with Service registry. I'm using ServiceMix 4.3.0 with embedded Felix instance. I have 2 bundles in my project.

The first one contains interface, and mock implementation. I want to publish them to OSGi service registry:

```
public interface PersonAPI {
    public void listAll();
    public List<PersonEntity> getAll();
    public void addPerson(PersonEntity pe);
    public PersonEntity getPerson(int id);
}
```

PersonEntity is a simple class with data, nothing special.

Mock implementation is contains just a list of PeopleEntity objects, so there is nothing interesting either.

Here is part of Spring configuration XML:

```
<bean id="personImpl" class="com.osgi.Person.impl.mock.PersonImpl" />
<osgi:service id="personLogic" ref="personImpl" interface="com.osgi.Person.PersonAPI" />
```

And part taken from pom.xml file:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.4</version>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<configuration>
    <instructions>
        <Bundle-Category>sample</Bundle-Category>
        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        <Export-package>com.osgi.*</Export-package>
    </instructions>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

This installs fine on ServiceMix. Now I defined another bundle, here are most important parts:

```
public class PersonTester {
    PersonAPI api;

public void init() {
    System.out.println("PostConstruct:");
    System.out.println("Have API " + api + " class " + api.getClass().getCanonicalName());

    api.listAll(); //This line (or any API call, blows everything)
}

public PersonAPI getApi() {
    return api;
}

public void setApi(PersonAPI api) {
    this.api = api;
}
}
```

Spring configuration:

```
<osgi:reference id="personLogic" interface="com.osgi.Person.PersonAPI" />   
<bean id="personTester" init-method="init" class="com.osgi.Person.PersonTester">
    <property name="api" ref="personLogic" />       
</bean>
```

Most important parts from pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>Pserson-API</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
....

<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.4</version>
<extensions>true</extensions>
<configuration>
    <instructions>
        <Bundle-Category>sample</Bundle-Category>
        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        <Import-package>com.Person.entity,com.osgi.Person</Import-package>
    </instructions>
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

The good news is, that "behind" injected Spring proxy is my implementation class. I can see that when using api.toString(). However when I call any method defined in my proxy, I get an exception:

> Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-88" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
>   with name 'personTester': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: AOP configuration seems to be invalid: tried calling method [public abstract void com.osgi.Person.PersonAPI.listAll()] on target [PersonImpl [set=[]]]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   object is not an instance of declaring class

It looks like It looks like AOP is missing the target, but why? And how to fix this?

Comment: On the risk of stating the obvious: could it be that your `com.osgi.Person.impl.mock.PersonImpl` doesn't actually implement `PersonAPI`? If not, the AOP system and the rest of the system probably load the `PersonAPI` class from different sources.

Comment: Hi Angelo, double checked, everything is fine. PersonImpl correctly implements PersonAPI. I didn't notice any classpath problem, so this is the "correct" PersonAPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is fixed. It was something in the environment.

I started building new project (with different artifact Id) on top of [this tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/ws-osgi-spring2/index.html) and everything looks OK. Perhaps something cached somewhere (strange, because I flushed ServiceMix bundle cache and local maven repo). I try to reproduce it on different machine, and maybe I'll come up with some better explanation.